# Need to redirect to given controller

Tags: magento2, event-observer, redirect-url

I need to redirect to ('hello/Test/Customer') page but observer is not working.

```
<?php
namespace SimpleMagento\Custom\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Addinfo implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $redirect;
    protected $url;
    protected $responseFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $redirect,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory
    ) {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->_responseFactory=$responseFactory;
    }

    /**
     * 
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $customRedirectionUrl = $this->url->getUrl('hello/Test/Customer'); 
        $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customRedirectionUrl)->sendResponse(); 
        die();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the event name that you used to redirect?

Comment: <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="update_customer" instance="SimpleMagento\Custom\Observer\Addinfo" />

Comment: after customer register success you want to redirect custom controller Right ??

Comment: yes. Exactly...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to redirect

```
protected $_response;
protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
    ...................................
    ...................................
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseInterface $response,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ...................................
    ...................................
    ){
    ...................................
    ...................................
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_response = $response;
    ...................................
    ...................................
    } 
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
    ..........................................................
    ..........................................................
    ..........................................................
    // solution - 1
    $customRedirectionUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('hello/Test/Customer');
    $this->_response->setRedirect($customRedirectionUrl)->sendResponse();

    //or you can try this 

    // solution - 2
    $controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
    $url = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getUrl('hello/Test/Customer');
    $controller->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
    return $this;

    ..........................................................
    ..........................................................
    ..........................................................
    }
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***