# This observer is not running at all

Tags: magento2, event-observer, url

This is **Observer**.

```
    <?php
namespace SimpleMagento\Custom\Observer;

//use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class Another implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $redirect;
    protected $url;
    protected $responseFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $redirect,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory
    )
    {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->redirect = $redirect;
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customurl = $this->url->getUrl('hello/Test/Customer');
        $this->_responseFactory->create()->serRedirect($customurl)->sendResponse();
        die();
    }
}

?>
```

The event is

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="customer_register_success">
        <observer name="new-data-add" instance="SimpleMagento\Custom\Observer\Another" />
    </event>
    </config>
```

Provided controller url is working fine (cheched in browser) but not with observer `hello/Test/Customer` . 
Same page is redirecting as soon as you successfully register.(data not going to database and not even observer working)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need to redirect to given controller](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/298313/need-to-redirect-to-given-controller)

Comment: Observer names must be unique per event definition. please check once.

Comment: no no... That is also a question. But not getting answers

Comment: $this->_responseFactory->create()->serRedirect($customurl)->sendResponse();  here is the spellmistake "setRedirect" .. check once

Comment: @purnagattu fixed that but not running even after that

Comment: Try to log first your observer and see if it works, just `$this->_logger->info('ok it works'); inside execute` without any redirection

Comment: @PЯINCƏ not giving result.  Same page is redirecting (register page).

Comment: @Akash Killedar ok, give me please the path of the event file

Comment: @PЯINCƏ app/code/SimpleMagento/Custom/etc/events.xml

Comment: @Akash Killedar try : `php bin/magento setup:di:compile && php bin/magento c:f`

Comment: @PЯINCƏ not worked..:-(

Comment: @PЯINCƏ even if I change whole module with other working observer module(in different laptop), observer is not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102066/discussion-between-pinc-and-akash-killedar).

Comment: try to print log before redirection with the following code                                  $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/import-new.log');
                $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
                $logger->addWriter($writer);                                                                         $logger->info($customurl );

Answer (score 0):

Update a code to

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
      <event name="customer_register_success">
         <observer name="customer_new_data_add" instance="SimpleMagento\Custom\Observer\Another" />
       </event>
  </config>
```

Comment: need upgrade after that?

Comment: bin/magento c:f , flush cache only

Comment: not worked..:-(

Comment: have you checked logs?

Comment: Can you please tell me the whole process ? where to find it and what to do with it.

Comment: va/logs/ where check debug.log , exception.log and system.log

Comment: [2019-12-11 07:13:51] main.ERROR: Error: Application is not installed yet.  [] [] . This is the last. and 480 cache_invalidate are there

Comment: even if I change whole module with other working observer module(in different laptop), observer is not working.