# Magento 2 - Redirect to an URL after downloading a file

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php

I want to redirect the user to an URL after downloading a file.

What I tried to do:

```php
$this->fileFactory->create('file.pdf', $pdf);
return $this->_redirect($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
```

But it never executes the return statement.

How would I go about this problem?

Comment: for redirect try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/302222/82670

Answer (score 1):

> **try this code**

```
<?php 
namespace Vendername\Modulename\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class Actionname name extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $uploaderFactory;

    protected $filesystem;

    public function __construct(
    ...................................................................
    \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
     ...................................................................
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_fileFactory = $fileFactory;
        $this->directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
     }

    public function execute()
    {
    
        $name = date('m-d-Y-H-i-s');
        $filepath = 'export/export-data-' .$name. '.pdf';
        $this->directory->create('export');

        ...........................
        ...........................
        ...........................     

        $content = [];
        $content['type'] = 'filename'; // must keep filename
        $content['value'] = $filepath;
        $content['rm'] = '1'; //remove csv from var folder

        $pdffilename = 'data-import-'.$name.'.pdf';
        return $this->_fileFactory->create($pdffilename, $content, DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, this code won't work in my case because after I run this line:
```php
$this->fileFactory->create('file.pdf', $pdf);
```
the code after it won't be executed.

Comment: please check updated answer and Update me

Comment: It works, but not in my case. I can't declare a route to redirect to.

Comment: it's works for me . it automatically download and close on new browser tab. if you need to redirect page you need to declare route.